# OnePlus One not found in Android Studio on Mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, oneplusone

I have a strange problem while developing in Android Studio on mac and i am using OnePlus one. While debugging if a call come on my mobile adb disconnect my device and don't show it again. Help me to solve this permanently. 
Only solution that i have found and which works is in following step:

1. Restart mac
2. disconnect cable from mac and OnePlus One
3. Kill adb server
4. start adb server
5. Revoke developer certificate and turn off developers option.
6. restart onePlus One
7. Turn on OnePlusOne and connect device with mac
8. Open Android Studio
9. Enable developer option and then enable debugging option

After I follow these steps, fingerprint dialog show and once I allow that dialog, device starts to show.
This process is time consuming. I am facing this problem on mac.

Comment: Until you find a permanent solution have you thought about using Genymotion emulator?  https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Answer (score 2):

Putting the phone in airplane mode seems to have temporarily fixed the issue for me. I still need to look at the logs and figure out what is wrong, but there seems to be a bug in the latest 5.x updates for the OPO.

Comment: surprisingly, this worked for me. Any update since july?

Comment: Still failing for the OPOX, this workaround is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EasyTether? If yes, you can disable it by using the following command:

`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext`

If that does not work, open System Information utility and check your device manufacturer ID  (Vendor ID). Copy that and paste it into your adb usb config by using

`echo 0x9d17 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

Then restart your macbook and mobile phone and try if it works.

Comment: Hi, how did you get this value "0x9d17" Is this the value obtained from lsusb command?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons your phone may not be getting detected properly, in my case it showed my phone in My Computers, and also asked me if I allowed my PC to debug on my phone. Yet it wasn't showing the phone in the android studio adb devices drop down menu.

All I did was, go to

> Tools>Android>Enable ADB Integration

and it found my device. This is once I had installed my OPX driver that shows as a disk in My Computers and also Samsung USB driver. I'm talking about Windows here but the solution applies to Android Studio on any platform. So thought I should share.